# Why Does My if Statement Ignore the 1st if?

Tags: if-statement, nested-if

When I run my code and select option 3, no matter the number I input, it always returns "No good, ...".

My code works fine for option 2 and will give me the correct cout statement, so I don't understand what the problem is with my code in option 3, as they're basically the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the point of logical operators, since first `if` and second `if` are not the same. You're requiring a number to be both lesser than 50 AND bigger than 75, in order to enter that `if` statement, which can never be true. You might want to switch to an or (`||`).